# Saving a Grails GORM/Domain class results in a `NullPointerException`

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I have a service that's responsible for creating the relevant account hierarchy when a registration page is successfully filled out :

```
    def userRole = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
    final account = new Account(email: command.email, password: command.password)
    account.save(flush: true)

    final publisher = new Publisher(name: command.name) //, account: account)
    publisher.save(flush: true)

    final accountRole = AccountRole.create account, userRole
```

Regardless of what I do, the `AccountRole.create account, userRole` fails at this line:

```
static AccountRole create(Account account, Role role) {
    def instance = new AccountRole(account: account, role: role)
    instance.save()  // throws NullPointerException
    instance
}
```

I have tried `new AccountRole(account: account, role: userRole)`, but this too fails when I manually call `save`. The `Account` and `AccountRole` are classes generated (and tweaked slightly) by the Grails 3 Spring Security plugin.

Here's the stacktrace for the `AccountRole.create(...)` call that fails:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.groovy:102)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.groovy:69)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at package.AccountRole.create(AccountRole.groovy:48)
    at package.RegistrationService.$tt__handleNewRegistration(RegistrationService.groovy:25)
```

Version information:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.5
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_73
```

Please save me from my misery! I've spent hours on this now :(

Comment: Can you provide a sample application with this behavior? I can only thing of your domain class not in the correct directory, so it's not a domain class actually.

Comment: The Publisher portion of this example seems irrelevant... might want to take that out.  I've also never used "final" for local variable declarations, especially ones that will change (as they do when you "save").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really enough info to be sure, but it's unlikely that `instance` is null since you just created it with a constructor call, but you should check that to be sure, e.g.

```
static AccountRole create(Account account, Role role) {
   def instance = new AccountRole(account: account, role: role)
   println "instance null? ${instance == null}"
   instance.save()  // throws NullPointerException
   instance
}
```

It's more likely that a problem during validation is causing the exception, so my guess is that there's something wrong with either `userRole` or `account`. Check that `userRole` was correctly retrieved and that there aren't validation errors from the Account `save()` call:

```
def account = new Account(email: command.email, password: command.password)
account.save(flush: true)
if (account.hasErrors()) {
   log.warn "Failed to save Account $account: $account.errors"
}
```